# convert pdf to image using .net 3.5

Tags: c#, image, pdf, .net-3.5

i need to convert an archive pdf in image, after a lot of searches and tries 
i tried with abcpdf lib , but , the version of .net(3.5) that i used is incompatible.
i tried with Spire lib , but , the result was unsatisfactory , low quality

```
private List<String> converterPDF(String path, String fileName, String extensao)
{
    List<string> listaArquivos = new List<string>();
    Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument();
    doc.LoadFromFile(path + fileName + extensao);
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)doc.SaveAsImage(i);
        bmp.Save(path + fileName + ".bmp");
        listaArquivos.Add(path + "@" + fileName + "@" + ".bmp");
    }
    return listaArquivos;
}
```

some posts here in the stack, but , nothing i can use to make it work.
some idea how i can resolve that ?

Comment: Elaborate - we are good but we can't read minds soz... 'unsatisfactory , low quality' ? erm

Comment: I just tried your package, and the free version of it allows me to convert up to 3 page per pdf file. Decent quality (in my view) but pretty annoying

Comment: did you want each page to be an image? PDFsharp can easily turn a page and save it as a seperate JPEG. Not sure if thats what you are looking for though.

Comment: Paul Zahra, when i say 'unsatisfactory , low quality', the point is , texts like a mario bros 16 bits, don't serve to me, do OCR in a image like that is a problem, even so , thank you for your time.

 Paradise228, i appreciate your try , but, i need a better solution for thhat problem, thanks.

Dylan, I believe have already tried that(pdfsharp), but i'll see again, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Spire. support team directly? I contacted them via E-mail before and they did help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you won't find any free decent and native pdf rendering API on .Net Framework.

Here is a solution using a great c/c++ api through P/Invoke. The author gives a detailed explanation on how to integrate the api into your application and how to use it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/498317/Rendering-PDF-Documents-with-Mupdf-and-P-Invoke-in